# How to manage the wals dir on a PostgreSQL replication server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL 9 servers running on Amazon EC2. One is the master, the other is a replication server in standby.

The replication server is continuing to fail as the hard drive fills up. It appears that the following directory is constantly growing:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/wals
```

There are thousands of files like:

```
-rw------- 1 pgsql users 16777216 Jan  3 20:36 000000010000001B000000A2
-rw------- 1 pgsql users 16777216 Jan  3 20:40 000000010000001B000000A3
-rw------- 1 pgsql users 16777216 Jan  3 20:46 000000010000001B000000A4
```

How do you set this up to not cause failure? Do you need to auto-rotate the wal files? Or? Could really use your advice. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure an `archive_cleanup_command` in your `recovery.conf` file.  Check out [`pg_archivecleanup`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgarchivecleanup.html); it's made for this purpose.

The WAL files could also serve as an archive for backup and recovery purposes, so they are not automatically deleted if you are just doing replication.

(Alternatively, you could use whatever hand-crafted method you like to clean up the archive, but that could be a bit difficult and error prone.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the **postgresql.conf** file called `wal_keep_segments=` and `checkpoint_segments=` I have mine set to `wal_keep_segments=128` and `checkpoint_segments=128` with replication fine.

`wal_keep_segments` are the minimum wal_files in the directory.
`checkpoint_segments` are the maximum.

I set it on both.

Comment: This is for the master or slave or both?

Comment: I clarified some stuff in the original answer

Comment: Thanks but I'm using 9.1, and I do not see a setting for wal_keep_segments, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-wal.html

Comment: Take a look here:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-replication.html

Comment: I added the configs and started the db server. All the wal files are still there...

Comment: Sorry, Got me stumped. Up voting your question, would like to see a better explanation myself.

Comment: @AnApprentice You said your slave was failing; if it's already hosed you need to reinitialize it with a fresh copy of the master to get back to a healthy state. Just setting the GUCs and restarting won't fix it if it's too far behind to get consistent.